# I/O buffer error in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a weight matrix (W) which is of size 400 x 8537.

Each cell in **W** has some numeric value.

Now I am trying to create another Y matrix of size 100 X8537 by the following analytical solution implemented in numpy.

Here **X is a 400 x 100** numeric matrix and
**P is a 300 x 8537** matrix , therefore P[:,i]= 300X1 vector.

```
for i, Wi in enumerate(W.T):
            Y[:,i] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
                                 np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), P[:, i])))
            print('{}th row of Y is completed'.format(i))
```

The problem is that since **W.T is 8537 x 400**, the above step is iterating 8537 times and adding one column at a time to Y matrix.

After some 1100+ iterations it throws the following error :

```
1109th row of Y is completed
1110th row of Y is completed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-d3bf04b641ea> in <module>()
----> 1 top_N_items=IMF(df_pref_sample.values,df_conf_sample.values,X,Y)

<ipython-input-59-30994c977fdc> in IMF(P, W, X, Y)
    105             Y[:,i] = np.linalg.solve(np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X)) + lambda_ * np.eye(n_factors),
    106                                  np.dot(X.T, np.dot(np.diag(Wi), P[:, i])))
--> 107             print('{}th row of Y is completed'.format(i))
    108 
    109         weighted_errors.append(get_error(P,W,X,Y))

\\dwdfhome01.wdf\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.pyc in write(self, string)
    315 
    316             is_child = (not self._is_master_process())
--> 317             self._buffer.write(string)
    318             if is_child:
    319                 # newlines imply flush in subprocesses

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

How to overcome this and get it done fast and run without error?

Thanks

Comment: The traceback includes `...\ipykernel\iostream.pyc ...`, which makes me think you are running this in ipython.  It should work there, but it would be worthwhile trying to run it from the command line instead of in ipython.

Comment: Yes I am running it on Jupyter notebook. I found this link here, but not sure what is the solution. 

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9168

Comment: If you follow the links in the issue, you'll get to https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/123, in which the problem has been fixed.  That was in April, so the fix probably isn't in a release yet.

Comment: In the meantime, the solution (work-around, really) is to run the code outside of ipython/jupyter, if you can.  Or just remove that print statement--it looks like it is only there so you can monitor the progress of the calculation.

Comment: Yes removing the print statement makes it work

Comment: `Wi[:,None].prod(X)` should be much faster than `np.dot(np.diag(Wi), X))`